# How can I get 3D object dimensions in ThreeJS?

Tags: json, 3d, three.js, maya, dimension

I'm developing an AR application using WebRTC (webcam access), JSARToolKit (marker detection) and threeJS (3D library).

I want to place 3D objects (exported from Maya using threejs maya exporter) in the center of the detected marker.

This is the code where I load the 3D object using JSONLoader:

```
// load the model
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader;
var object;
//var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
loader.load('js/cube.js', function(geometry, materials){
var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

object.position.x -= ***3DobjectWidth/2***;
object.position.y -= ***3DobjectHeight/2***;
object.position.z -= ***3DobjectDepth/2***;

scene.add(object);
});
```

I need to get width, height and depth of the object to change his position (see ***3DobjectWidth*** ecc).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object size will be placed at `geometry.boundingBox`. But it has to be generated once.

try this.

```
geometry.computeBoundingBox();
var bb = geometry.boundingBox;
var object3DWidth  = bb.max.x - bb.min.x;
var object3DHeight = bb.max.y - bb.min.y;
var object3DDepth  = bb.max.z - bb.min.z;
```

Comment: I actually need to translate only y position using bb.min.y for my purpouse. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Geometry has a .center() method. That might be more efficient and simpler if you need to center many meshes based on same geometry. It also calls computeBoundingBox for you.

Comment: I use different 3D models, various products.